# Damaged PDF created (0 bytes) with iText

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I'm trying to generate and share a PDF using iText. I don't get any error with the code below and can actually view the PDF.

However when sharing the file I notice that it weighs 0 bytes, and obviously I get an error message 'file might be damaged' when trying to open it.

Any idea what's wrong?

I'm using com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.2.

```java
public void ConvertToPdf() {

    String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/users.pdf";
    File file = new File(path);

    if(file.exists()){
        try{
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    document.open();

    Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 14);
    Font font_title = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 24);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_270x270);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image img = null;
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        try {
            img = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("FICHIER PDF",font_title));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(currentTime),font));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

    try {
        document.add(img);
        document.add(paragraph);  
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(PdfCreationActivity.this,"PDF Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onsharePDF() {
    String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/users.pdf";
    File file = new File(path);

    if(file.exists()){
        Intent share = new Intent();
        share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        share.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivity(share);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you *can actually view the PDF*, it cannot be a *0 bytes* file.

Comment: PDF file is 8o..

Comment: *"PDF file is 8o.."* - Even 8 bytes are not enough for a valid PDF you could view. But you might want to share those bytes, they might help in analysis. By the way, if `file.exists()` then `file.createNewFile()` is documented to do nothing, so why do you do that?

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElkXT2HH7U99qFSVFwJtKHxkXsORkGpt/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a PDF file generated :

Comment: Ok, that indeed *is* a 0 byte file. But as mentioned above, you cannot have *actually viewed* this PDF which you claimed you could, simply because there is nothing to view in a 0 byte file. Thus, I assume you have timing issues, either `onsharePDF` occurs _before_ `ConvertToPdf` finished, or it occurs _after_ some other code again cleared the file, e.g. a next call to `ConvertToPdf`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I get a toast once pdf is generated so I don't think onsharePDF occurs before ConvertToPdf finished.

Comment: I need to precise that to "view the PDF" I have another activity :
'''
        String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/users.pdf";
        File file = new File(path);
        pdfView.fromFile(file)
                .swipeHorizontal(true)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .password(null)
                .load();
    }

'''

Comment: @YannChevalier Are you able to view the file attached to one of the messages above with the "another activity" you mentioned above?

Comment: @YannChevalier I tried to reproduce the issue using your code (with the only alteration in bitmap being not processed and therefore image being not added), and the resutlant PDF is generated and looks as expected. Could you share some code/minimal project which we can try out and see the issue?